# How to mark/highlight the current/enclosing scope we are in in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, is there a way to highlight/mark/show the current scope, i.e. method name or class name we are (the cursor is) currently in?

It is time-consuming to scroll up until I find the enclosing scope, especially when the method content is long.

#### EDIT:

I already understand that there is a bluish line on the left-hand side marking the current scope, but what I want is the method or class name, because we still need to scroll up/down for that.

Also, when we put our cursor right after the closing bracket of the scope, we get the name of it at the top, when the scope is longer than one page, but this also requires me to scroll down to the closing bracket at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the "Structure" tab (showing the class structure), and check the 'Autoscroll from Source' button (top right).
Then each time you click anywhere in a method, the method you are in is highlighted in the Structure tab.

If you want to know in which class you are in, just click on an empty line between methods, and the encompassing class will be highlighted instead.

You can also check the 'Autoscroll to source' button for jumping from 'Structure' tab to source. Or use the F4 key while selecting a method in the tab.

Note: I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1.